# HitTest with CAShapeLayer doesn't work

Tags: ios, path, collision-detection, hittest, cashapelayer

I use the following code to check wether a point of a player is in a circle area:

```
if ([circle.presentationLayer hitTest:player.position])
{
    NSLog(@"hit");
}
```

My circle is a CAShapeLayer:

```
CAShapeLayer *circle = [CAShapeLayer layer];
CGFloat radius = 50; 
[circle setMasksToBounds:YES];
[circle setBackgroundColor:[UIColor redColor].CGColor];
[circle setCornerRadius:radius1];
[circle setBounds:CGRectMake(0.0f, 0.0f, radius *2, radius *2)];
[self.view.layer addSublayer:circle];
```

The collision detection works very well that way.

Now I don't want to hittest the player's position with a circle layer but with a CAShapeLayer drawn along a custom path:

```
CAShapeLayer *customLayer = [CAShapeLayer layer];
customLayer.path = customPath.CGPath;
customLayer.fillColor = [UIColor yellowColor].CGColor;
customLayer.shouldRasterize = YES;
customLayer.opacity = 0.2;
[self.view.layer addSublayer: customLayer];
```

When I want to hittest the player's position with the custom layer the hittest doesn't work anymore.

How can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 2):

Are you converting the position to the correct relative position?

For example:

```
CGPoint layerPoint = [[dynamicView layer] convertPoint:touchLocation toLayer:sublayer];
```

Also, perhaps you need `CGPathContainsPoint`:

```
if(CGPathContainsPoint(shapeLayer.path, 0, layerPoint, YES))
{
```

Answer (score 2):

You are assigning the bounds/frame of your circle, but not that of your bezier path. I did not know that until I stumbled onto it myself, but when you create a shape and assign a path to a CAShapeLayer(), you *must* assign the CALayer's frame (or separately the position and the bounds) because the frame of a CALayer(), as per Apple's documentation, defaults to a CGZeroRect and does not get automatically updated when you set the path. hitTest() is based on the position+bounds (or frame) and therefore fails.  The documentation says:

> /* Returns the farthest descendant of the layer containing point 'p'.
>    * Siblings are searched in top-to-bottom order. 'p' is defined to be
>    * in the coordinate space of the receiver's nearest ancestor that
>    * isn't a CATransformLayer (transform layers don't have a 2D
>    * coordinate space in which the point could be specified). */
>
> - (nullable CALayer *)hitTest:(CGPoint)p;
>
> /* Returns true if the bounds of the layer contains point 'p'. */
>
> - (BOOL)containsPoint:(CGPoint)p;

A quick unit test shows this (extension CGPath is useful and included after):

```
func testShapeLayer() {
    let layer = CAShapeLayer()
    let bezier = NSBezierPath(rect: NSMakeRect(0,0,10,10))
    layer.path = bezier.CGPath
    // remove the following line to FAIL the test
    layer.frame = NSMakeRect(0,0,10,10) 
    XCTAssertNotNil(layer.hitTest(CGPoint(x:5,y:5)))
    XCTAssertTrue(layer.contains(CGPoint(x:5,y:5)))
}

extension NSBezierPath {

public var CGPath: CGPath {
    let path = CGMutablePath()
    var points = [CGPoint](repeating: .zero, count: 3)
    for i in 0 ..< self.elementCount {
        let type = self.element(at: i, associatedPoints: &points)
        switch type {
        case .moveToBezierPathElement: path.move(to: CGPoint(x: points[0].x, y: points[0].y) )
        case .lineToBezierPathElement: path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: points[0].x, y: points[0].y) )
        case .curveToBezierPathElement: path.addCurve(      to: CGPoint(x: points[2].x, y: points[2].y),
                                                            control1: CGPoint(x: points[0].x, y: points[0].y),
                                                            control2: CGPoint(x: points[1].x, y: points[1].y) )
        case .closePathBezierPathElement: path.closeSubpath()
        }
    }
    return path
}
```

}

Yet, that's probably not what you want: you want the path to be used for hitTesting(), not just the frame.  I would therefore probably add an extension to your hitTesting routine: if the CAShapeLayer() is hit, it means that it is within the frame, then you can be more specific and check with CGPathContainsPoint() like the other answer mentioned.

Comment: The path can be outside the frame so better to just check the path.contains(point) - but be sure to convert the point to the layers coordinates.  Usually the point would be in the views coordinates which may not be the same if the layers position has moved.